# Can BIRT be used within a web application without deploying a separate web application on the server?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, birt

Can I use BIRT within my application instead of deploying as a separate app on the webserver?

I know that BIRT viewer can be integrated with the application by installing it on the server. I went through the process and its very cumbersome. It requires me to import too many JARs and then code too much even for a simple report.
Jasper on the other hand does this elegantly.All I need is 2-3 JARs and 5 lines of code to generate a simple report.
Is it possible to accomplish the same with BIRT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to add just the report engine (and possibly the report designer) to your application, and have everything happen via code, instead of URL from the viewer.  But you'll have to implement your own viewing functions, e.g. paging through the report, and if you need the report in different output formats, there's code you'll have to write for that, too, instead of letting the viewer application do it.

Comment: I am aware of the method of adding report engine to the application and using it. This method takes too much of an effort for generating a report because I need to do all the report formatting, paging etc from code instead of a designer. I wanted to know whether it is possible to just generate the report and view using a single app war, while still design using the designer tool.

Comment: You can design using the designer tool and deploy the report design as a resource in your application's .war.  You can generate the report from the design using the report engine.  Viewing the report depends on the format you want to use -- if you want to generate and deliver a PDF, no problem straight from the report engine.  But if you want an HTML report with paging, that's runtime interpretation of the generated report.  You can use the viewer application, or write your own, but something needs to deal with the back and forth from browser to report object.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy the open source viewer, which will allow you to do this.  There is also a BIRT Reporting Web Project you can create using Eclipse's Web Tool Platform that will create a web project for you to run BIRT reports in.  (BIRT WTP Integration download)

http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/intro/intro02.php